Does this sentence sound like a suggestion?
A: I need to fix the roof.
B: No worries. If your application for the pension gets approved, you can use the money to fix it next month.
Does the sentence in bold sound like a suggestion with "can"?

Why you ask so many questions about “can”? I don’t think you should argue with that too much in English.

The "can" merely expresses "ability".
Of course, by making a point of telling someone that they are able to do something, I am suggesting the idea.  But this isn't as strong as "You should use the money"
Polite speech is tentative.  Instead of saying "Do something" or "You should do something", you say "You can do something".  It is a tentative and more polite way to talk.

Thanks for replying. Can I say B is suggesting an available way to spend his money to A?

I don't understand the problem.  There is nothing special about English use of "can".  We are social animals and we understand socially.  If a teacher says to a student "The board needs to be cleaned"  Is the teacher "stating", "suggesting" or "commanding" the student.  It depends on the particular social situation.  "Can" expresses ability.  What else is impled must be understood from the nature of the relationship, not the words.
